# Error when install Matterhorn

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, bigbluebutton

I'm using BigBlueButton (BBB).

I want to record and playback the video files as showed-off [here](http://www.diigo.com/annotated/74d0863b1c08348003d94c09e024d8e6) by BBB but the feature is not ready until next version of BBB as its owner Fred Dixon stated [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bigbluebutton-dev/NYT703eaLyw/QpWwo4ddRvsJ).

As advised, I start using Matterhorn for processing and playback.

I'm following this guide to install Matterhorn 1.3 on Ubuntu 11.10:
http://opencast.jira.com/wiki/display/MHDOC/Install+Source+Linux+v1.3

When step run Matterhorn

```
sh /opt/matterhorn/felix/bin/start_matterhorn.sh
```

then I get the error message:

```
Auto-properties start: file:lib/org.apache.felix.scr-1.6.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:lib/org.apache.felix.scr-1.6.0.jar - java.io.FileNotFoundException: lib/org.apache.felix.scr-1.6.0.jar (No such file or directory))
Auto-properties start: file:lib/org.apache.felix.eventadmin-1.2.12.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:lib/org.apache.felix.eventadmin-1.2.12.jar - java.io.FileNotFoundException: lib/org.apache.felix.eventadmin-1.2.12.jar (No such file or directory))
Auto-properties start: file:lib/org.apache.felix.metatype-1.0.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:lib/org.apache.felix.metatype-1.0.4.jar - java.io.FileNotFoundException: lib/org.apache.felix.metatype-1.0.4.jar (No such file or directory))
Auto-properties start: file:lib/org.apache.felix.http.bundle-2.0.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:lib/org.apache.felix.http.bundle-2.0.4.jar - java.io.FileNotFoundException: lib/org.apache.felix.http.bundle-2.0.4.jar (No such file or directory))
...
```

and similar error message to shown above

I've researched it and tried to run the command line as `sudo java -jar opt/matterhorn/felix/bin/felix.jar`
then get error message to shown above

How to fix error when start Matterhorn server ?

Comment: It has been answered in [BigBlueButton mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bigbluebutton-dev/0AIlejldrGE/tJy42iS-7t4J)